# NOT IN clause in query takin too much time to execute

Tags: sql-server

I have to filter out rows from a table say A (contains only 1 column ) that are not present in table B (contains many columns).

Apart from the only column in table A there is no other column that I can use.

So I am currently using the NOT IN clause but it is taking too much time to execute.

No room for Joins due to single common column

Please suggest your views

Comment: You can try to create an index on the column, for faster "NOT IN" searching

Comment: You can't join on a single column why?

Comment: Can you share an example query please? It's possible that this could be solved with SELF JOIN but more information is required from you in order to determine this.

Comment: Say Table A contains ColumnA with entries 'A','B','C','D' and Table B contains ColumnA with entries 'B','C'. Now I want the entries that are there in Table A but not in Table B for ColumnA. Currently I am using "SELECT ColumnA from Table A where ColumnA NOT IN (Select columnA from Table B)"

Comment: I tried using CTE as well as temp table to store the temporary result set of the nested query but as long as NOT IN exits in the query its taking to much time

Comment: If the column is nullable `NOT EXISTS` [can be more efficient as described here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/) please post the execution plan and table structure including indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT IN` (as well as `<>` for example) cannot be optimized with B-Tree organized indexes. So unfortunately you cannot do anything with this issue.

Comment: Are you trying to say that it doesn't matter what indexes exist for a `NOT IN` query because this is definitely not the case.

Comment: @Martin Smith: I'm trying to say that `NOT IN` and `<>` cannot be optimized with B-Tree indexes, thus - for query processing fullscan will be performed.

Comment: I see what you are saying in that the first input will need a full scan but Indexes can definitely be helpful. SQL Server can use a merge anti semi join if it knows that both inputs are sorted for example or use an index to seek into the second input.